# PHP mcrypt and redirect errors/problems

Tags: php, encryption, web, header

I have two problems.

1) I am having a problem decrypting information using mcrypt.

Encryption code:

```
$username = mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_SAFER128, "*password*", $username, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT);
$password = mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_SAFER128, "*password*", $password, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT);
echo "
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
<!--
document.cookie = 'username=$username; expires=0; path=/'
document.cookie = 'password=$password; expires=0; path=/'
//-->
</script>
";
```

This seems to work fine.  I checked the cookies in my browser that (without the mcrypt statements) had the username and password and they looked like gibberish.  I used this to decrypt:

```
$username = $_COOKIE['username'];
$password = $_COOKIE['password'];
$username = mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_SAFER128, "*password*", $username, MCRYPT_DECRYPT);
$password = mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_SAFER128, "*password*", $password, MCRYPT_DECRYPT);
```

And got this error:

Warning: mcrypt_cbc() [function.mcrypt-cbc]: Module initialization failed in * file path * on line 14

2) I am trying to do a redirect using php.  I was using javascript, but a user can turn it off and then the redirects won't work.  So I used the following:

```
header('Location: *URL*');
```

and I get this error:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at * file path and line number *) in * file path * on line 31

I've tried searching this, and a bunch of people seem to have this problem, but I can't seem to get it to work.  I have the php code for this above any HTML code, but I still get the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1.) the output of mcrypt_ecb is not string-safe. base64-encode it after encryption and decode it before decryption

2.) headers must be sent before any other text - this means not only no "echo", "print*" etc. but also no text outside of  tags in your files. Common error is whitespace or a BOM marker at the beginning of a .php file

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the encryption stuff either tomorrow or this weekend.  As for the headers, I have all the PHP stuff above all the html stuff, so there are no tags and there are no echo or print statements before the redirect, so I have no idea where whitespace would be coming from.  I'm using Dreamweaver, could that be causing the problem?

Comment: I can't comment on Dreamweaver. A good way to look for whitespace is to open your files in a hex editor and find out, if the first byte is 0x3C